# Username Check with return object directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm just trying to implement usercheck directive which return user object with success user checking. but i'm unable to bind return object to model once complete user check what was the mistake i have done. my directive as follow

```
app.directive('usernameAvailable', function($timeout, $q, $http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
      model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() { 
        return $http.get('backend.json').then(function(res){+
          $timeout(function(){
            var data = res.data; 
            model.$setValidity('usernameExists', !!data.valid);
            model.userModel = res.user;
            scope.$apply();
          }, 1000);
        }); 


      };
    }
  } 
});
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lz4Xg4NEYdbarJ0lByND?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you write the user to the 'model', which is a ngModelController. Wouldn't the scope be a better place?

Comment: so what you suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCABRMK6vKQU7RnxilGw?p=preview). Hope this helps... I used `.success` instead of `.then` and I wrote the user object into the scope.

Remark: In this example it is working fine, but it you write a directive with it's own scope the user object wouldn't be visible.

```
link: function(scope, elm, attr, modelController) {
  modelController.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() {
    return $http.get('backend.json').success(function(data) {
      $timeout(function() {
        modelController.$setValidity('usernameExists', !!data.valid);
        scope.user = data.user;
      }, 1000);
    });
  };
}
```